# jquery autocomplete _renderItem to add image tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am trying to use jquery autocomplete and custom html to add a image in my dropdown.  for some reason, when I set up the image, the autocomplete looks fine when I enter a name (I see the picture and the label just fine), but when I arrow down to select, i get an error that says ui.item is not defined for focus and select events.  If I follow that standard format shown in the example page, everything works fine.

(the one from the jquery doc - works as expected)

```
.append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.value + "</a>" )
```

but when I use this one to show an image, the autocomplete lists shows with pics, but the focus and select events dont work

```
$( "#friends" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: friend_data,
    delay: 0,
    autofocus: true,
    focus: function(event, ui) {
        $( "#friends" ).val( ui.item.label );
        return false;
        },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#friends" ).val( ui.item.label );
        return false;
        }    
    })
    .data( "autocomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        var fb_pic_path = '<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/' + item.value + '/picture?type=square">' ;
        console.log(fb_pic_path);
        return $( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .append(  fb_pic_path +  item.label  )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };
```

Comment: use firebug and console.log statements to determine where it breaks..so its easy to check and fin a solution for your issue

Comment: just check the line that creates the "fb_pic_path" to check if it has been constructed correctly.

Comment: thanks for the response.  I did that and the url is fine.  in fact, the rendering of the autocomplete is fine with a pic..  I just somehow lose the select and focus events (no ui.item defined) once I arrow down..  so nothing can ever be selected

Comment: ah..  figured it out.  needs the anchor.  .append( "<a>" + fb_pic_path + item.label + "</a>" ) and it works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ah..  figured it out.  needs the anchor.

```
.append( "<a>" + fb_pic_path + item.label + "</a>" )
```

and it works fine now.